# Why can't I load GLScene as a package in C++Builder?

Tags: package, c++builder, firemonkey, bpl, glscene

I am trying to use [GLScene](http://glscene.sourceforge.net) (a third-party FireMonkey component for C++Builder and Delphi). I downloaded the zip, and in it, among other things, are .bpl files for use in C++Builder. When I try to install the package in my project (a C++Builder multi-device application) under Component > Install Packages... > Add, I get this error:

[image: Error: can't load package...]

#### My directory structure:

[image: Directory structure and files]

The _Installation directory and the Readme's are not very helpful. I have tried the other .bpl files and also tried importing all of them at once, but the same error occurs. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

- The XE3 extension is suspicious. I just downloaded and unzipped the GLScene download. The .BPLs in the CBXE3 and CBXE4 seem to be compiled for XE3 and XE4 respectively. But packages are version-dependent.
  **You should recompile the sources (also included) for 10.2 Tokyo.** Just copy the DelphiXE4 directory to a new directory, and load the `.groupproj` file or the single `.dpk` files into the IDE. You might want to change the suffixes (currently `XE3`) of the packages to, say, `Tokyo`, in the project options, to avoid DLL (or BPL) hell.
  Also take a look at the pictures in the `_Installation` directory for the other options that must be set. Note that your paths may differ, theirs are just an example.
- The compiler needs to be able to find the `.bpi` and `.lib` etc. files in order to be able to link. Set the directories with those files in the project options, as shown in the `_Installation` pictures.
- The newly compiled `.bpl` files should be **compiled to a directory on the Windows path**, so they can be found by the system at runtime. In their example setup, (and in the `_Installation` pictures) that is the shown `C:\Library\GLScene` path.